# How to Minimize main-thread work for my blogger website?

Tags: blogs, pagespeed

I have run google developer speed test of my website and I got some bad score for mobile users, though I am using a responsive theme.

there are many problems showing to diagnose and I am not much of a coder to don't know much about coding. 
Please, can anyone tell me how to speed up my website?

[image]

The main problem occurring due to these:
4
Minimize main-thread work

Avoid enormous network payloads

Reduce JavaScript execution time

Avoid an excessive DOM size

Here I am attaching a screenshot of that and link for my website is

Comment: To help people with coding problems, it is what SO is intended for, not with the questions that violate multiple rules on how to ask a good question. The real question you wanted to ask is why is the OP on SO if he is not doing any coding?

If the question is valid, why have you not answered? Because it would take you a couple of books to explain to a person that knows nothing on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use font swap option for *webfont visible error* and defer JavaScript for minimizing the main threadwork. I did it this way and it worked.